# How many $n$-element subsets $A$ of $\{1,2,3,\cdots,2n\}$ with specified sum are there？

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

**Question:**

> Let $ n$ be an postive integer number.and let $A=\{x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}\}$, How many $ n$-element subsets $ A$ of $ \{1,2,\dots,2n\}$ are there,such $$x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}=\dfrac{n(2n+1)}{2},or,\dfrac{n(2n+1)}{3}$$

My idea:

if we Assmue that  $f(n)$ is  numbers of subset such this problem condition

if $n=1$,it is clear $A=\{1\}$ such 
so only one  subsets such this condition.then $f(1)=1$

(2):if $n=2$,then $1+2+3+4=10=2\times 5$,so only two subsets $\{1,4\},\{2,3\}$such it
 then $f(2)=2$

(3): if $n=3$,then $1+2+3+\cdots+5+6=21=3\times 7$,then only one subsets such it
$\{1,2,4\}$,then $f(3)=3$

but for general $n$,how can find this closed form $f(n)$

**Now,  Henning Makholm found if $n\equiv 5\pmod 6$,then**
$$f(n)=0$$

But other case,We can't know.

This problem is from:[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004248/how-to-solve-problem-similar-to-imo1995-problem)

Comment: If $n\equiv 5\pmod 6$, then $n(2n+1)$ is divisible by neither 2 nor 3.

Comment: but other case？

Comment: I'd be very surprised if there was any closed form. If $p_n(x,y)=\prod_{i=1}^{2n} (1+x^iy)$, then you are look for the coefficients of $x^{n(2n+1)/2}y^n$ and $x^{n(2n+1)/3}y^n$ when those exist. I'm gonna bet the best you can do is an approximation or some truly disgusting formula that sheds little like.

Comment: Using @ThomasAndrews's function you get that the $x^{n(2n+1)/2}y^n$ and $x^{n(2n+1)/3}y^n$ coefficients of $p_n(x,y)$ for $n = 1,\ldots, 15$ are

$$\{0,2,0,8,0,58,0,526,0,5448,0,61108,0,723354,0\}$$

and

$$\{1,0,1,2,0,7,15,0,69,152,0,808,1892,0,10745\}$$

respectively. The first sequence, without the zeros is generated by [A063074](http://oeis.org/A063074). The second sequence is on the site.

Answer (score 1):

This question of mine
is, I think,
related:

[How many different ways can the signs be chosen so that $\pm 1\pm 2\pm 3 ... \pm (n-1) \pm n = n+1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482376/how-many-different-ways-can-the-signs-be-chosen-so-that-pm-1-pm-2-pm-3-pm)

Since
$1+2+...+(2n)
=\frac12(2n)(2n+1)
=(2n+1)n
$,
then
if a subset sums to
$\frac12 n(2n+1)
$,
the rest also sum to
$\frac12 n(2n+1)(n+2)
$
so the sum
$\text{sum(original subset)-sum(others)}
=0
$.

Therefore
this is a choosing of signs
for the integers from
$1$ to $2n$
so their sum is zero.

For the second case,
if the first sum is
$\frac13 n(2n+1)
$,
the rest sum to
$n(2n+1)-\frac13 n(2n+1)
=\frac23 n(2n+1)
$
so their difference is
$\frac13 n(2n+1)
$
and this does not have
an obvious interpretation,
unlike the first case.